# Windows 10 setup.exe lost support for /m?

Tags: windows-10

**setup.exe** (the program which kicks off the Windows installer) as distributed in the Windows 10 general release no longer supports the /m option; this option let you specify a directory to copy into the newly installed system.

This option was really useful ...

Has anyone found a similar mechanism for distributing program installers/scripts/data into the newly installed OS, so that they can continue setup of the system on first boot?

Comment: You mean like a [provisioning package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn916107(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: In previous versions of windows (and the windows 10 preview releases ...) passing /m:arg_path to setup.exe would configure the installer to copy a magic directory of content from within arg_path into a location on the newly installed system -- eg if i had a directory foo at arg_path/$1/foo (where $1 is just an arbitrary name required by the installer) -- then after setup completion, the newly installed system would have a directory c:\foo.  unattend.xml could be configured to invoke c:\foo\my_foo.exe to kick off arbitrary system provisioning processes from within the live os environment ...

Comment: Yes, it's done so since Windows 95. I don't see that functionality anymore.

Comment: Hmm that's a bummer ...  I guess I'll have to look into the "provisioning packages" you linked to -- though it seems like overkill for my use ...